# Parse Facebook login_success URL

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

After I authenticate with Facebook I'm getting this URL:

```
 http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
 #access_token=161713100507627|2.R8bXAgr9wdiQYWJgVx_yPg__.3600.1301475600-100001169602345|sY-
fl-62kCSgcn1pgiv2fYsltHE
 &expires_in=5996
```

How can I parse this URL and get the access token?

I tried `request["access_token"]` but it's not working: I cant get anything after the `#`.

the code that genrate the url

```
 string[] extendedPermissions = new[] { "publish_stream", "offline_access" };

        var oauth = new FacebookOAuthClient { AppId = current.AppId, RedirectUri = urlli };


        appId = current.AppId;
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "response_type", "token" },
                        { "display", "popup" }

                    };




        if (extendedPermissions != null && extendedPermissions.Length > 0)
        {
            var scope = new StringBuilder();
            scope.Append(string.Join(",", extendedPermissions));
            parameters["scope"] = scope.ToString();
        }

        var loginUrl = oauth.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that gives you this URL?

Comment: i added the code that genrate the URL

Comment: which platform? Silverlight? WP7? Windows Forms? Web? It helps me figure out where you can find an answer quickly..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have enough info to be able to answer you somewhat. I'm guessing you are using Silverlight out of browser (since that is the only platform that I know of that returns like this).

What you have to do is set up a page on the same site where your silverlight out of browser app is installed from (you have no choice you MUST do this). The reason is that you will not be notified of anything after the hashtag. Essentially what the page does is do a ScriptNotify to the Silverlight app passing in the full URL from JavaScript (it will include the hashtag content -- the "#access_token=..." stuff).

You will also need to set up in your facebook application (I think you can also do this in your call in the setup in your code as well) to point to this page. In your Silverlight you just simply have to handle the "ScriptNotify" event. See [here for the sample web page](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c0b97eff9e21#Samples/CSSilverlightOutOfBrowser/SilverlightClient.Web/slfblogin.htm), and [here for the sample Silverlight code](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c0b97eff9e21#Samples/CSSilverlightOutOfBrowser/SilverlightClient/MainPage.xaml.cs)

One more thing, please mark me as the answer if I have correctly guessed (and solved) your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hit http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/261528 with my WPF app -- this may also apply to Silverlight. This is an interaction between a change in Facebook behavior and an issue with the WPF (and Silverlight?) WebBrowser control. I was able to work around my issue by switching to WinForms. The link discusses an alternate approach which stays with WPF but adds a call to FacebookOAuthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken().